# How to get the output from the SAP SOAP WSDL from wsclient++ in Android

Tags: android, soap, sap, windows-client

With using wsclient++, generated files for WSDL to be invoked from the web service. Added that generated files in my project in Android. Then after how to write the code and how to generate the steps.

But I am not understanding how to call the exact method for getting output in Android. Can some body help me in brief?

Comment: I guess the question is valid for any SOAP webservice, whatever they originate from SAP software or any other one...

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in IOS. may be this code can help you a bit.

```
mPayMobilePayment *mpayMobilePayment =[mPayMobilePayment service];
```

//mPayMobilePayment is service name, and you will call getService method in the same way.

```
[mpayMobilePayment setBaseUrl:@"Enter your complete base url, you can get this url easily from soapUI tool as well"];

NSError *error;
NSArray *response = [mpayMobilePayment getSubscribedEntityServices:@"firt input value of method. input values will be auto generated" entityId:@"second input value of method" error:&error];
```

getSubscribedEntityServices" is my method name in service and this method is autogenerated by WSClient.

every code i wrote is auto generated by wsclient in its files. i just copied the files in my project and call them in the above decsribed way.

Hope this will help you out.